What is Pan tool for in AE?
As I see it, Pan in AE simply moves the object (like the Selection Tool). By the way, the Pan Under Cursor Tool and the Pan Camera POI Tool work exactly the same.

What does Pan actually do in AE (the Selection Tool and Pan cannot perform the same functions)? And what is the difference between the Pan Under Cursor Tool and the Pan Camera POI Tool?
